# Getting the `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, any hint on how to solve?

Tags: vim

I have installed Vim on my mac, I have no `.vimrc` nor `.vim/` folder. It is a clean vim installation.

I try to use a command like `:grep foo` as you see in the video but I don't get results and get only the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` that breaks the flow and make vim unusable.

Here is a demo: https://streamable.com/ulf0z4

What it can be?

I tested some things like:

set cmdheight=2

set shortmess=a

on nvim instance that I have on the same mac, but the results are the same.. I don't know where to start to debug the problem. Any help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're having no results because there are no results to your grep command... You might be interested in reading `:help grep`, and `:help message`. Vim's grep is not the same as unix's grep. If you don't want to use vim's grep, you should try the command `:!grep` (see `:help :!`)

Comment: Even with results it shows the first one and the the message "Enter ."

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify which files you want to apply grep on. `:grep foo ./*`

grep fills the quickfix list which can be accessed with `:copen`

read `:h silent` to avoid the error message.

`:h  redraw` might be interesting as well.